# ActiveX Control will not resize or move

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, com, activex

I am developing a C# application that runs instrumentation. I would like to include some ActiveX controls provided by the manufacturer. I have installed and registered the controls and added them to my tool box in Visual Studio. When I add the control to my form it is forced to the upper left hand corner (0,0) and size (0,0). If I try to resize or move the control in the properties menu it returns to (0,0). When I add the control to my toolbox it ends up in my "General" category.

I have tried setting the size programmatically as well. If I set a minimum or maximum size I can retrieve a non-zero size from the control but I will not see the control in my form. The control is quite old, and works in VB6 in XP virtual desktop. Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you can add it into a `WebBrowser` control, for example by using the `<object classid="clsid:THE_ACTIVE_X_GUID">` syntax. Not sure it will help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per Sjips suggestion I opened up the ActiveX control using the `WebBrowser` Control within my form. With the HTML Code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <center>
    MVC Diplay
    <p></p>
    <div id="DivId">
      <script>
        var mvc = document.createElement('object');
        DivId.appendChild(mvc);
        mvc.width = "800";
        mvc.height = "500";
        mvc.classid = "CLSID:78559301-09D8-11D2-85D3-204C4F4F5020";
      </script>
    </div>
  </center>

</body>

</html>
```

It was also required to add the following to the "Post-build event command line:"

`call "$(DevEnvDir)..\tools\vsvars32.bat"`

`editbin.exe /NXCOMPAT:NO "$(TargetPath)"`

I also had to set the build target to x86.